# Undefined type CustomUITextField class from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I'm trying to use a UITextField from `TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder` cocoapods (https://github.com/taiking/TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder) inside a `UITableViewCell`.

I've added a `UITextField` inside the Prototype Cell in the storyboard, changed its class to `TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder` and it works fine when I run the app.

BUT, I need to set its placeholder property programmatically, so I've created the `@IBOutlet` to this `UITextField` to my `UITableViewCell`. Unfortunately, it does not recognize the type TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder. Xcode shows the error Use of undefined type `TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder`.

I need it to be this custom type so, in my `ViewController` I can access its `placeholder` property - I've also tried to cast the `UITextField` to `TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder`, with no success. I've tried some other pods, but they all ended up throwing the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

FieldTableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class FieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var textField: TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder! //Use of undeclared type 'TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder'

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

UIViewController.swift (snippet)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FieldTableViewCell") as? FieldTableViewCell else {return
                UITableViewCell()}

            cell.textField.placeholder = "My dynamic string" //ERROR
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
}
```

Comment: Well not sure how you are including this library to your project but it appears you have not used "import TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder" in your source code, hence the compiler is unable to recognize it.

Comment: I've installed it using Cocoapods. I'll give a shot at your suggestion, but I'm almost certain I've already tried this approach and the error remained. Will update this comment in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the library in your file and the error will go away.

```
import TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder
import UIKit

class FieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var textField: TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder! //Use of undeclared type 'TextFieldFloatingPlaceholder'

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: WOW, it worked! One question: does the order of the imports matter? Or do I have to build the project in order it to work properly? For some reason, the import was failing yesterday, but now it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that the order matters. Specially here.